# How can I change the user that I am using for smartface

Tags: smartface.io

When I started the smartface ide first time I entered my email and password, Now I want to use another user, How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 'Welcome ... logout' on right bottom corner.You can log out pressing 'logout' in here and log in with another user.

Comment: I think It is very hard to find it :)